# Google Cloud Data Loss Prevention Service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp

With the Cloud DLP service, I was curious if there is the ability to have a Central Project where you can create all of your Job Triggers and Inspect Templates, and from there scan a GCS Buckets/BigQuery located on a separate project. Is this possible? Or is it the case where the DLP API will need to be active on each project individually, and Inspect Jobs/Job Triggers created on each individual project?

Currently when defining the URL for the bucket within my Job Trigger, it will only list out the GCS buckets located on my project. If I try to still define a URL "gs://mybucket/*" of a Bucket located on another project, I receive an error. Would this come down to just a SA permissions issue? Or just that it's not a capability of the DLP service?

I just wanted to check here to double check that I'm going down a path that is even a possibility. All answers/insight is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After doing a bit more testing, providing Read Permissions on the GCS Bucket side to the Google Managed DLP Service Account, you are able to scan from one project to the other.

Comment: This setup (a central driving project) is a common pattern done by data governance and security teams that wish to centralize management. It's true that the auto complete UI input elements don't make suggestions across projects, but it'll function fine if you manually enter.